# scrollToItemAtIndexPath causing app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to scroll my UICollectionView to the top via code. I am calling this method:

```
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

The crash:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

Not too sure exactly how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is my collection view method - I'm loading three different type of cells if condition is met:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{   static NSString *tableCellIdentifier = @"TableItemCell";
    static NSString *gridCellIdentifier = @"GridItemCell";
    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    if (indexPath.item < [self.tradeSearchArray count]){

        if (self.gridLayoutActive == NO){

            self.switchToTableLayout = NO;
            BBItemTableViewCell *tableItemCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if ([self.tradeSearchArray count] > 0){

                self.toolBarButtomItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Results", self.searchResult.searchResults];

                self.switchToTableLayout = NO;

                tableItemCell.gridView = NO;
                tableItemCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                tableItemCell.item = self.tradeSearchArray[indexPath.row];

            }
            return tableItemCell;
        }else

        {

            BBItemTableViewCell *gridItemCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:gridCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if ([self.tradeSearchArray count] > 0){

                self.toolBarButtomItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Results", self.searchResult.searchResults];
                self.switchToTableLayout = YES;

                gridItemCell.gridView = YES;
                gridItemCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                gridItemCell.item = self.tradeSearchArray[indexPath.row];

            }

            return gridItemCell;
        }
    }else
    {

        BBLoaderCell *loaderCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LoaderCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        loaderCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    if (self.maximumOffset - self.currentOffset <= 1000.0) {
        [self loadMoreSearchResults];

        if (self.loadingMore){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
                [loaderCell.spinner startAnimating];
            });
        }
        else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
                [loaderCell.spinner stopAnimating];
            });
        }

        return loaderCell;
    }
}

    return nil;

}
```

Comment: Re-read error message and check (and may be post here) code of method that caused problems

Comment: paste your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Updated the question with the collection view method. Thanks guys

Comment: From apple docs:
indexPathForRow:inSection:
Returns an index-path object initialized with the indexes of a specific row and section in a table view.
indexPathForItem:inSection:
Returns an index-path object initialized with the indexes of a specific item and section in a collection view.

So please check out @Radu response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line

```
return loaderCell;
```

is inside the the `if` statement

```
if (self.maximumOffset - self.currentOffset <= 1000.0)
```

Therefore, on occasion the method will return `nil` when it should have returned a `loaderCell`.

Comment: Thank you - that solved the crash and the original problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this mean it should never return nil for cell?

Comment: @Wingzero Yes, that is correct, you must never return `nil` from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this for scrolling to the top:

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Still crashing though. :(. All I want it the tableview to be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]` see if that works

Comment: indexPathForRow is not indexPathForItem

Comment: Crashes either way with similar message. Thanks